# NGINX - Rename Permission Denied While Reading From Upstream

Tags: php, nginx, rename, permission-denied, upstream

I recently switched from Apache to Nginx.  PHP language underneath and using fastcgi_pass to php7.4-fpm to run all script file.  Everything seems to be working fine.  Pages are working, PHP is executing, all assets loading fine, etc.  However my nginx error log is getting flooded with these errors:

> 2020/11/19 06:28:52 [crit] 3332114#3332114: *26646323 rename()
> "/tmp/0012831123" to "/opt/www/example/web/controller.php" failed (13:
> Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 104.220.189.242,
> server: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), request: "GET
> /path1/path2/path3/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host:
> "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/"

I have been trying to Google this for a week, and there just is nothing.  Tried looking at permissions on nginx cache files, etc, but nothing.  I really am stumped at this.  I have no idea why some tmp file would be trying to get renamed to an actual file that should be executable.  This seems bad, and kind of scary.

Any help or advice on where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[TLDR]
To save others from spending a ton of time on this as I have.  There is a configuration setting 'fastcgi_store', it needs to be set to 'off'.

Basically there is a 'fastcgi_store' setting that allows to copy files, or maybe dynamically generated files, to disk.  Not sure exactly what the use case this is for, but in my '..../snippets/fastcgi-php.conf' file this was enabled.  Considering I am fairly new to NGINX, I probably copied this over from somewhere without really understanding what it is used for or the repercussions of it.

The main problem, I assume, is that there were bad permissions somewhere and the files could not be written.  This is probably a good thing, as the files would have quickly filled up my webserver disk space.  Since I did not need these files, I just disabled it and didn't look into the permission issue further.

Here is a link to nginx documentation about this:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_store

Change in conf file:
fastcgi_store off;

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me (on macOS) was that the NGINX cache folders at the following location did not have read/write permission:

```
/usr/local/var/run/nginx
```

Granting read-write permissions for these folders via the Get Info dialog sorted out the problem.